# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'xxx/?wsdl' : Premature end of data in tag html line 1

Tags: php, web-services, zend-framework, soap, wsdl

For days now, I've an error and no way to find a solution to fix this.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>WSDL</faultcode><faultstring>SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.domain.com/?wsdl' : Premature end of data in tag html line 1
```

For information, this wsdl work in our production environment, when I try to get it work on my dev environment we got this error.

- First, I tried to try this file with SOAP UI, got exactly the same
  error.
- I tried to exploit it with an external PHP script, same error.

For example :

```
$wsdl = "http://www.domain.com/?wsdl";
$service = new Soapclient($wsdl);

$params = array('username' => 'xxx', 'password' => 'xxx');
var_dump($service->__soapCall('myFunction', $params));
```

- I tried to use NuSOAP library like some people seem to fix it with
  this, it doesn't for me.
- I checked firewall
- I tried these solution https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49226 none
  work
- I checked my php.log :

> PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'http://www.domain.com/?wsdl' : Premature end of data in tag html line
>   1  in /data/srv/www/.../library/Zend/Soap/Server.php on line 762

Did some search about this and didn't find any solution to fix it.

Did I miss something ? Have you any idea how to fix this ?
If you need more information, just ask.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What happens when you open your wsdl URL with firefox (that usually display XML)?

Comment: All fine when I open URL www.domain.com/?wsdl.
I'm just getting error when trying to access function.

Comment: try `$wsdl = "http://www.example.com/?WSDL";`

Answer (score 0):

load the API from your server. 
download the wsdl/xml  on your server,
point your $wsdl => point to server file/